# Messaging with Faye : ReferenceError: Faye is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye

I am using Faye websockets in my Rails application, just like Railcasts # 260.
All was fine, but now I am getting error like

> ReferenceError: Faye is not defined

here

```
$(function() {
    var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
    faye.subscribe("/games/messages/new", function(data) {
        eval(data)
    });
});
```

I started my faye like: `rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production`

**faye.ru**

```
require 'faye'
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
run faye_server
```

I don't know what's going on, the only thing I changed was install rails-unicorn gem and default booting from it.

UPDATE: 
http://localhost:9292/ says:

### Sure you're not looking for /faye ?

And if I add /faye -

### Bad request.

And if I add /faye.js -

### js script of Faye

UPDATED: For a now it just works, don't know why, but it is. Thank you, all.

Comment: Why yes, where are you defining `Faye`? Is it included in JS files above the file in question?

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'user',  "http://localhost:9292/faye.js" %>

Comment: Inspecting with firebug says that faye.js realy included

Comment: All this doesn't answer my question. Is `Faye` defined there?

Comment: Yes, it is, some kind of strange stuff. But now it works

Comment: Uhm... works now? Answers not needed anymore? This question should then be closed as the problem still hasn't been identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use your actual `ip` instead of `localhost` in `Faye.Client` initialization in production environment(of course use [`request.host`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-host) helper for this):

```
var faye = new Faye.Client("http://#{ request.host }:9292/faye");
```

Comment: @KyleKorver what does `curl your_ip:9292` say?

Comment: Sure you're not looking for /faye ?
And if I add /faye - Bad request. 
And if I add /faye.js - js script of Faye.

Comment: it is correct, strange, sorry, but then I don't know

Comment: Could it be something with browser settings ?
But I am using both: chrome and firefox.